# Link always runs in cemu elmulator

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, keyboard, cemu-emulator

Is it possible to somehow make Link walk in cemu-emulator? He always seems to run when I press forward motion key on keyboard, it's little uncomfortable for me to make him always run even when he should not.

Comment: There is no toggle in the game's settings for that? An auto-run feature?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "run". He sprints which uses stamina, and then he "runs" which doesn't use stamina, but this is dependant on the level of input

Comment: @Ben i meant normal running not sprinting(uses stamina) , i've heard in switch or controller if we slightly move the forward motion stick he will walk , how can we do  it in keyboard

Comment: I cannot guarantee this (which is why I'm posting a comment, not an answer), but this is all dependent on the level of input. You can't do "soft" or "hard" with a keystroke. You might be able to do it with the mouse wheel; but again I cannot guarantee that/tell you how that can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve that with the keyboard, because your arrow keys (and any key for that matter) only have a binary state: **ON** and **OFF**. When emulating the joystick with the keyboard, this means your joystick only emulates a 100% input all the time, resulting in Link running (without using stamina). You'll have a hard time whenever you need to move slowly, including hunting and sneaking around undetected.

I strongly suggest you to buy any **USB joystick**, with dual analogue sticks. I've purchased a Logitech wireless joystick and the keys arrangement is perfectly suited to replace the Classic Controller Pro. Also, the vibration feedback improves your gameplay experience as well, check if the joystick includes vibration before purchase.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [guide](https://gamerwelfare.com/2022/08/26/cemu-with-mouse-and-keyboard-new-method/) to set up Mouse2Joystick. The speed Link moves at will reflect the distance you move your mouse.